# reCAPTCHA form submitting twice on second submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I am creating a form using reCAPTCHA v2 and want the form to be able to be submitted again without reloading the page. When I submit the form for the first time, it works as expected. However, when I submit the form again without reloading the page, my CaptchaValidate function will be called twice, first returning false, then returning true. Why is this happening? Any help would be brilliant, thanks.

HTML

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
        
        <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="myKey" data-callback="onSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function onSubmit(response) {
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formData = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/CaptchaValidate',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: { dataToken: response },
                success: function (resultData) {
                    if (resultData == 'true') {
                        //do something
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.error-message').html('could not submit form');
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
        }).submit();
        grecaptcha.reset();
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> GetCaptchaData(string dataToken)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string secretKey = "mySecretKey";

    var res = httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretKey + "&response=" + dataToken).Result;

    if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        return "false";

    string JSONres = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    dynamic JSONdata = JObject.Parse(JSONres);

    if (JSONdata.success != "true")
        return "false";

    return "true";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`
it stops the rest of the event handlers from being executed.

```
function onSubmit(response) {
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // new line
            

                const formData = $(this).serializeArray();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/CaptchaValidate',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: { dataToken: response },
                    success: function (resultData) {
                        if (resultData == 'true') {
                            //do something
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.error-message').html('could not submit form');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            }).submit();
            grecaptcha.reset();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason on the second submit it initially returns false, though should return true. So I am wondering why it returns false and how to prevent this. If the page refreshes after submit then it will work fine again but without refreshing it behaves differently.